# Android Studio - New Empty Activity - cannot resolve symbol R.layout.activity_newname

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio 3.6.3

When I create a new Empty Activity in Studio by right-clicking on "New => Activity => Empty Activity", it creates the java class and the xml layout file.

However, in the new Java class onCreate() method, it doesn't recognize the 'R.layout.activity_newActivity' symbol.

[image]

Here's theXML file it genereated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".test123">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It added this to the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<activity android:name=".test123"></activity>
```

What am I doing wrong? I have tried a Clean and Rebuild. No help. This happened to me once before a long time ago, but of course, I can't remember now how I made it work.

Comment: Search command "Invalidate cashes/restart" in Android Studio

Comment: That did it. Why did I have to do that? Do I have to do that every time I create a new Activity?

Comment: Every time when you see some magic that you don't want to see )